# Send notification when code deploy rollsback

Tags: aws-code-deploy

we are using AWS CodeDeploy and would like to have a notification when a roll back occurs due to failed deployment.

Do we set the Events that trigger notifications to be "Failed" in this case? Was expecting to have a Roll back choice.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rollback is not available as a notification type on the Application level, but on the Deployment Group level. Inside the Deployment Group, go to "Triggers" and you will be able to chose "Deployment rollback" as option under Events.

More information on this in the [CodeDeploy docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/monitoring-sns-event-notifications.html).

[image]